# Continuity proof with epsilon-delta

Tags: real-analysis

Let $K > 0$ and let $f:\ \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ satisfy the condition $\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert \leq  K \lvert x - y\rvert\ \forall x, y \in \mathbb R$. Show that $f$ is continuous at every point $c \in\mathbb R$.

I have no idea where to begin :(

Comment: Also, if someone can point me in the right direction on how to use MathJax. It doesn't work for me clearly...

Comment: I'll edit it for you.

Comment: For mathjax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This is a stronger condition, called Lipschitz continuous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you want to pick $\epsilon>0$.  Now suppose your points $x$ and $y$ are in a neighborhood of each other of length $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{K}$.  Does this seem like a reasonable place to start?

Comment: I think get it from there then. The fact that there is both x and y as variables threw me off, but I can just treat y as any c in R that is in the neighborhood of x? Does that make sense?

Comment: @JLIU Yes, you got it.  The condition that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq K |x-y|$  is that if you pick any two point $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ then the distance of their images under $f$ will be bounded by their original distance times some constant factor $K$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Cheers!